# Consistent superscript placement with sideset

Tags: amsmath, superscripts

Consider the following MWE which uses `\sideset` from AMS math to typeset a primed summation with an upper limit:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
 \sideset{}{'}\sum_{i=0}^m x = \sum_{i=-1}^{m} x
\]
\end{document}
```

where it is evident that the vertical placement of the upper limit of the sum, `m`, is different for the primed and non-primed summations.  Is there a simple means, in the case where the upper limit does not impinge on the limits introduced by sideset, to have these both typeset consistently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not pretty:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
 \mathop{\smash{\sideset{}{'}\sum}\vphantom{\sum}}\limits_{i=0}^m x = \sum_{i=-1}^{m} x
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The same idea, but better integrated with `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\psum}{%
  \DOTSB\mathop{%
    \smash{\sideset{}{'}\sum}%
    \vphantom{\sum}%
  }\slimits@
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\psum_{i=0}^m x = \sum_{i=-1}^{m} x
\]
\end{document}
```

A more complicated solution for making TeX into believing that the summation symbol has the right width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\psum}{\DOTSB\psum@}
\NewDocumentCommand{\psum@}{e{_^}}{%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th\displaystyle'$}\kern-\wd\z@\!%
  \mathop{%
    \kern\wd\z@
    \smash{\sideset{}{'}\sum}%
    \vphantom{\sum}%
  }\psum@scripts#1%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\psum@scripts}{mm}{%
  \slimits@\IfValueT{#1}{_{#1}}\IfValueT{#2}{^{#2}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\psum_{i=0}^m x = \sum_{i=-1}^{m} x
\\
\sum_{i=-1}^{m} x = \psum^m_{i=0} x
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

In the example you see that you can input subscript and superscript in any order.

### Update

With more recent version of `xparse`, the above code should be changed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\psum}{\DOTSB\psum@}
\NewDocumentCommand{\psum@}{e{_^}}{%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th\displaystyle'$}\kern-\wd\z@\!%
  \mathop{%
    \kern\wd\z@
    \smash{\sideset{}{'}\sum}%
    \vphantom{\sum}%
  }\slimits@\IfValueT{#1}{_{#1}}\IfValueT{#2}{^{#2}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\psum_{i=0}^m x = \sum_{i=-1}^{m} x
\\
\sum_{i=-1}^{m} x = \psum^m_{i=0} x
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One quirk, which is hard to see at lower resolutions, is that the m for the primed summation is shifted right related to the regular sum.  I am unsure what is causing this, however.

Comment: @FreddieWitherden Yes, the width of the prime was taken into account. The new code should be what you wish.